# Multiply image resize & position in fixed-width div (to fill all the place)

Tags: css, image, resize, frontend

I need to post several images into fixed width div. Images are always different, with different widths and heights. My aim – to place them smoothly to fill all the area of my div. The best example of what I need to do was created by Vk.Com. Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you see, there is no matter how much users load images and which sizes are them. Vk.Com crops, resizes and fits all pictures in div of fixed width. How do you think, are there any open-source solutions to make this? Thanks to everybody.

**UPD:** loaded some really different images with absolutely wide-range dimensions.
[image]

Comment: I notice that each group of photos has it's own layout. I'm not sure if there's a plugin to use but I would create a set of styles for each case based on the number of images.

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to know if the images will upload dynamically or not, meaning that you may have the freedom to arrange images manually.

Comment: @otinanai sure, but there are only 5 examples of dozens layouts. It doesn't matter how much images do you load – the always find ways to place them. So, I mostly consider they process them without any common layouts 'cause dimensions are really different. And btw, you load images in preview box, they place it only when you click publish button, no dynamic re-position.

Comment: @otinanai loaded some really different images with absolutely wide-range dimensions. See the post update. And it seems they even enlarge images, if they are small (left bottom img was about 50x50 img in original).

Comment: I don't know if this is practical but you could always use Tim Thumb to re-size and crop the images on the fly. http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/

Comment: I see what you mean but still I think you can find a pattern here. I would create a jQuery script with 5 layouts. Each layout would represent a row of images (2-6 images). These images should always have the same height and crop them based on their orientation or resize them. I would then pick a random layout for each row of images so that they all look different when each set is prepared.

Comment: and to make things simpler, cropping and resizing can be greatly done with css. all you need is a parent div that will hide parts of the image or define the height of the image if set to 100%. My point here is that you don't need a server-side script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually far more complicated than I imagined. I knew there were some layout plugins that could fit regularly-sized images into a slotted layout ([Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/images.html)), and some that would fit randomly-sized images into a simple linear layout ([Automatic Image Montage](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/)), but I haven't seen any scripts that will take randomly-sized images, and resize them to fit into a slotted layout.

[This guy managed to work out the key features necessary for a Google Plus-style gallery](http://www.techbits.de/2011/10/25/building-a-google-plus-inspired-image-gallery/) (which seems similar to yours), but concludes that this depends upon server-side generation of multiple image sizes, and a bit of logic besides. However, he does produce a [pure Javascript reduced version](http://fmaul.de/gallery-grid-example/) at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Google+ style grid and Automatic Image Montage seem to be cool, however I need to resize images before I can use Automatic Image Montage, yes?

Comment: No, Automatic Image Montage resizes them automatically (in fact, when I load the page I first see all the images large and badly laid out, then resized and arranged).